# Optionalize properties in client app

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

I have written an app using Spring Boot and have properties in `application.properties` file. Now I am trying to build this app as fat JAR and use it another Service project as a dependency. As per the documentation I read, if I provide these properties available in client app again in Service’s `application.properties` file, Spring will override them else it will use the one available in client app.

I want to make these properties optional in client app while building it and asks Service app to provide them mandatorily. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share document what said `Spring will override them else it will use the one available in client app.`?

Comment: Spring will only use application.properties from the client app. Just copy & pasta it.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2013/10/30/empowering-your-apps-with-spring-boot-s-property-support     In this link in the "Overriding properties with more properties" paragraph

Comment: I do not want to let spring uses the client app properties becuase these properties are based on environments that means if Service app provides QA properties it has to create bean for QA or Prod based on the Service app needs. If I have to provide them in client app I can only do one environment and cannot let it to Service

Comment: I found it. I can build the Client app with @Value annotation without providing the properties in application.properties file. When the Service App have this dependency and try to run it without providing these properties it will through beancreationexception that is what I want. Thanks guys